# Qt mobile app client w/ SignalR .NET server

Tags: qt, qml, aspnetboilerplate, esri, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm planning to build Web application and use the SignalR library to allow web admin to chat with other users (use Mobile application)
1- System admin uses Web Application built by Asp.net Boilerplate (.NET Core 3.1).

2- other users use Mobile Application built by (Qt Mobile application )

So, Is this scenario applicable with the SignalR library, or I will encounter some limitations especially with QT Mobile application?

**Update:**

Why I want this approach?

Because I'm using Esri QML SDK (in Mobile App)

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with QT Mobile Application development, however I looked for it and understood that the language of development is C++.

Based on this, here is a client lib for SignalR in C++. You can use this lib to connect to c++
[Click Here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-Client-Cpp)

Also, I wish to bring attention to an official documentation from Microsoft that states that C++ & Swift are unofficially supported framework.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#unsupported-clients)

Comment: Based on your update, I suggest you to give the mentioned c++ sdk a try, if that doesn't work for you then its going to be a very difficult situation. Do come back with additional problems which you face.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used SignalR before. However, Qt provides its own websocket QML [client](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html) component as well as a [server](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocketserver.html) one, they have a client example [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/examples/websockets/qmlwebsocketclient/qml/qmlwebsocketclient/main.qml?h=5.15) and a server example [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/examples/websockets/qmlwebsocketserver/qml/qmlwebsocketserver/main.qml?h=5.13) should you want to see how the client component interacts.

I have used the QML websocket with a NodeJs [websocket server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) and it presented no problems at all.

Creating a simple working environment should be no problem, Qt provides its own simulator with their IDE, just copy the client example, change the link to point to your server and give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't got this up and running by now, I'll suggest you would take a look at [signalr-qt](https://github.com/p3root/signalr-qt). We have been using this for several years now, with Qt apps for iOS, Android and Windows desktop. Unfortunately it is not maintained anymore, but we've been running it in production apps using Qt 5.6, Qt 5.12 and Qt 5.15.

Comment: Thanks for including all the details on your successes with this per Qt version!  I need to get this working on Win/Mac/Linux/iOS/Droid, Qt v5.11 and v5.15, all at once.  I'm half way through the process of all that, and while it's proving to be a bit of a pain to do it all, I can confirm that this seems to be possible for all these contexts if you fiddle with some compilation errors and linkage hassles.  That said, I'd rather jump through a couple of days worth of hoops than role my own version of this from scratch!